# How Do I have multiple .xib files share a common backing class Swift 3 iOS?

Tags: swift, uiview, xib, abstract, iboutlet

I have a class, we'll call it `MyView` written in Swift 3 that extends `UIView`.
I have two view `.xib`s, we'll call them:
  * `MyViewStandalone.xib`
  * `MyViewEmbedded.xib`

The behavior should be 100% identical in the two views, but they look radically different. 
There are four `@IBOutlet`s (an `ImageView`, a `UIView` and two `UILabel`s) in each nib.

Whenever I try setting both of the "File's Owner" to `MyView`, I get this runtime error:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Blah.MyView 0x7f8e7d4427d0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key errorBannerLabel.'`

What I've done so far (but am not satisfied with), is to subclass `MyView` into `MyViewStandalone.swift` and `MyViewEmbedded.swift` which both have all their own `@IBOutlet`s.

I then added four getters:

`func getErrorLabel() -> UILabel
func getHeroImage() -> UIImageView`

etc…

Then, in the base class, instead of calling the view elements directly, all interaction is done through those getters.

My first thought was to implement the getters in the base-class and mark them **`Abstract`**, but we don't have that in Swift.

How would you approach this? How is this usually done?
How are the cool kids solving problems like this?